# Import error in the django tutorial

Tags: python, django, import

I'm trying to follow the django tutorial and create two tables where the unique key of table1 might appear several times on table2 (which has a different unique key)

```
CREATE TABLE "apples" (
    "id1" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "value1" varchar(400) NOT NULL,
)
;
CREATE TABLE "oranges" (
    "id2" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "id1" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "MyApp_apples" ("id"),
    "value2" datetime NOT NULL,
)
```

when trying to run:

```
import package
from package import MyApp
from package.MyApp import models
from package.MyApp import apples, oranges
p = apples.objects.get(id=1)
p.oranges_set.create(value2="2168164000000")
```

I get the error stack (I post only the end, if you need more, tell me please):

```
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 162, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named MyApp
```

I assume it's a problem with the imports, but how do I solve it?

Comment: Can you tell us sth about the files/folders involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `package` is the project name and `MyApp` the app for that project you don't have to import package in your files, you can just:

```
from MyApp.models import apples, oranges

p = apples.objects.get(id=1)
...
```

This is an error too:

```
from MyApp import models
from MyApp import apples, oranges // ImportError
```

`apples` and `oranges` are inside your `models.py`

Perhaps you also need to read about [modules and packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Hope that helps!